# Pass a class' member function in to a callback function?

Tags: c++, templates, wrapper

I have this template:

```
template <class T>
v8::Handle<v8::Value> jsFunctionTemplate(const v8::Arguments &args)
{
    T *t = static_cast<T*>(args.This()->GetPointerFromInternalField(0));
    if (t != NULL) t->volume(args[0]->NumberValue());
    return args.This();
}
```

I want to make it 100% dynamic, so I'm hoping to replace `t->volume` with a pointer (std::mem_fn?). The thing is, I can't figure out from similar examples/questions how to retain the jsFunctionTemplate's current type (it must be a `v8::InvocationCallback`)

```
typedef Handle<Value> (*InvocationCallback)(const Arguments& args);
```

So that it's usage can still be:

```
audio->PrototypeTemplate()->Set("Volume", v8::FunctionTemplate::New(&jsFunctionTemplate<Audio>));
```

I am not opposed to using even C++11 syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't claim to fully understand the limitations which the v8 API imposes here, but if a template argument for the type is all right, then I hope you can use a **pointer-to-member template argument** for what you want to achieve here. The following self-contained and tested example, although without v8, should demonstrate how this can be done:

```
#include <iostream>

struct foo {
  void bar(int arg) {
    std::cout << "bar(" << arg << ") called" << std::endl;
  }
};

template<class T, void (T::*fun)(int)>
void ptfWrapup(void* ptr, int arg) {
  (static_cast<T*>(ptr)->*fun)(arg);
}

int main() {
  foo f;
  ptfWrapup<foo, &foo::bar>(&f, 42);
}
```

Applied to your situation, and assuming `NumberType` to be the return value of that `NumberValue` call, or more importantly the type of the first argument of the functions you want to call, it would look something like this:

```
template <class T, void (T::*fun)(NumberType)>
v8::Handle<v8::Value> jsFunctionTemplate(const v8::Arguments &args)
{
    T *t = static_cast<T*>(args.This()->GetPointerFromInternalField(0));
    if (t != NULL) (t->*fun)(args[0]->NumberValue());
    return args.This();
}

… v8::FunctionTemplate::New(&jsFunctionTemplate<Audio, &Audio::volume>) …
```

In contrast to the example above, this here is untested, but on the other hand closer to your code. Together they should make the idea crystal clear, I hope.